# luminance ratio for shadow removal

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

In this paper: [Human Body Tracking by Adaptive Background Models and Mean-Shift Analysis](http://www.merl.com/reports/docs/TR2003-036.pdf)
Section 3, the authors mention about luminance ratio thresholds for bright[n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053345/median-variance-in-background-subtraction)ess and darkness (r1, r2).
Can anyone suggest what should the values be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have them explained  in [**this paper**](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=4A1BE1FD73D7F9B5C0C7C2FBF52B20DF?doi=10.1.1.87.1244&rep=rep1&type=pdf), sections 4.2 and 4.3.

I usually prefer to post self-contained answers, but this topic is not easy to understand without reading the whole paper.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the paper: [A statistical approach for real-time robust background subtraction and shadow detection](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Publication/2026552/a-statistical-approach-for-real-time-robust-background-subtraction-and-shadow-detection)  ... one doubt: in equation (6) shouldn't it be sqrt(sum of squares) ?